# How to have multiple highlighted colors in UIAlertController of action sheet style?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIAlertController of action sheet style, it has 2 normal actions and one cancel action, I wanted to have different colors of text for them and cus of this, I subclassed UIAlertController:

```
class CustomAlertViewController: UIAlertController {

internal var cancelText: String?

private let fontRegular = UIFont(name: "IRANSans", size: 16)
private let fontBold = UIFont(name: "IRANSans-Bold", size: 16)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
}       


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    self.findLabel(scanView: self.view)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.findLabel(scanView: self.view)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.findLabel(scanView: self.view)
}

func findLabel(scanView: UIView!) {
    if (scanView.subviews.count > 0) {
        for subview in scanView.subviews {
            if let label: UILabel = subview as? UILabel {

                if (self.cancelText != nil && label.text == self.cancelText!) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        label.tintColor = UIColor.red
                        label.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.green
                        label.font = self.fontBold
                    }
                } else {
                    label.font = self.fontRegular
                    label.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x2699FB)
                    label.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.black
                }
            }

            self.findLabel(scanView: subview)
        }
    }
}

} // class end
```

so now normal labels has blue color and cancel label has red color. but when I select them, I don't want them to highlight as same color. this is where problem accurs, it seems that the labels highlight as UIAlertController's view.tintColor. does anyone know how can I do what I want? I mean how can I define my own highlight color for different labels?

Comment: you can do this simply by setting the action item style to `.desctructive` instead of `.cancel`.

Comment: this way all labels appear in same section. not good enough for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Jafar Khoshtabiat, see below code for display red text in action sheet, I hope it's helps you. see following link for more details https://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

//UIActionSheet

```
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Takes the appearance of the bottom bar if specified; otherwise, same as UIActionSheetStyleDefault.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: "Destroy", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = .Default
actionSheet.showInView(self.view)

// MARK: UIActionSheetDelegate

func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    switch buttonIndex {
        ...
    }
}
```

//UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Takes the appearance of the bottom bar if specified; otherwise, same as UIActionSheetStyleDefault.", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
    // ...
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destroy", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
    println(action)
}
alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: tnx for answer, but I can currently show my red text, I want to change labels selection color